# Switching order of integration in proving linearity of expectation

Tags: calculus, statistics, fubini-tonelli-theorems

[proof of linearity of expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl1nd.png)

In this picture, when proving linearity of expectation, they switch order of integration in 3rd line. As I know about Fubini's Theorem, if value of integration is absolute convergent it can be switched.

But the first term in 3rd line, which turns into E(X) is not absolute convergent as I know (ex. Pareto dist, St.Petersburg paradox...).

Is there anything wrong with my thought? Why it can be switched?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: If $EX$ exists as  a real number then $E|X| <\infty$ automatically.